# A property of an anti-unitary operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I've been assigned to prove
$$
A \exp(-iB)A^{-1} = \exp(iABA^{-1})
$$
for $A$ being anti-unitary and $B$ Hermitian.

To my understanding, I should simply expand the exponent, insert a bunch of $1=AA^{-1}$, and commute $Ai=-iA$ when moving $i$ to the left in each term.

Question: why do I need to know that $B$ is Hermitian? Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're not missing anything.  This is true for any invertible antilinear operator $A$ and linear operator $B$.  Maybe the "Hermitian" is just to tell you that $B$ is linear rather than antilinear.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please clarify what changes if $B$ is antilinear?

Comment: Oops, nothing does.  It's just the same if $B$ is antilinear.